# Erro de invalid swift quando apple tenta processar app

Tags: swift

Olá! Estou tentando publicar um aplicativo na App Store da apple. O build faz normal e faz também o archive normal, mas após processar na apple, retorna o seguinte erro: Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app's Framework location, such as /Payload/MyPharma.app/Frameworks. Obs: estou usando pods no app. Já tentei inúmeras alternativas que não resolveram. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Uma sugestão, você poderia usar `$(inherited)` na tab Build Setting e procurar por "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES".

Answer (score 0):

Quando tive este problema era que minha app utilizava um framework A que dependia de outro framework B e eu somente tinha linkado o Framework A no meu projeto, ou seja, o problema é que algum framework que vc utilizava tem uma dependência que não esta sendo copiada junto com o binário, sem Cocoa Pods é somente linkar o framework faltante ao projeto, agora com o cocoa pods verifique a pasta para onde ele copia as dependências e veja qual esta faltando.